# How to return multiple search query using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search

I have a very simple form which is used to search for data on another website, The issue I am having now is how to return the query.

Here is my form

```
<form action="javascript:redirect()">
<label>Search :
<input id="search" type="search">
<select name="level" id="level1">                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  <option value="senior">Senior</option>
  <option value="junior">Junior</option>
</select>
</label>
<button type="submit">Search website</button>
</form>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function redirect() {
  var q = document.getElementById("search");
  var level = document.getElementById("level");
  var url = "https://someweb.com/search/?q=" + q.value;
   window.open(url,"");
  }
</script>
```

I want to return something like this

**https://someweb.com/search/?q=search-id&level=levelid**

ie. if i search for css and select junior, my browser should return

**https://someweb.com/search/?q=css&level=junior**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your level, then concat it to your url.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function redirect() {
  var q = document.getElementById("search");
  var level = document.getElementById("level");
  // Build level query string
  level = level.value ? '&level=' + level.value : '';
  var url = "https://someweb.com/search/?q=" + q.value + level;
   window.open(url,"");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you also want to check whether or not the input has data.